# How to change the name of a item that I am adding to a list of items

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class called Contact, and a list called contacts, which is a list of the Class Contact.

I have a variable named localContact, which is a Contact.

I want to add localContact, to my list contacts, but I do not want it to be named localContact in the list. I want it to be named localContact.Name (which is a string).

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean you want it named in your list? The list is just a collection of objects and without a reference to a particular item they aren't really named.

Comment: your question is unclear. how could the variable name relate to the run time value of the variable?

Answer (score 1):

use a dictionary instead of a list then:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Contact>();
myDict[localContact.Name] = localContact;
```

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you are talking about a ListBox control)

In the Contact class, override the `ToString` method.

something like:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Name;
}
```

Comment: No, I am talking about a list, not a listbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want to use a dictionary collection, so you can retrieve your Contact objects using Contact.Name as the key.

e.g.

```
// Create the collection
Dictionary<string, Contact> myCollection = new Dictionary<string, Contact>();

// Create your local object
var localContact = new Contact { Name = "MyLocalContact" };

// Add the local object to the collection
myCollection.Add(localContact.Name, localContact);

// Retrieve the local object by name
var myContact = myCollection["MyLocalContact"];
```

Comment: So if I set it up like so.

Dictionary<string, Contact> Contacts = new Dictionary<string, Contact>();

Add to the dictionary.

Contacts.Add(localContact.Name, localContact);

Then I can pull that item out of the list using the string that was stored in localContact.Name?

Apparently I cannot figure out out to format in this comment section :\.

Comment: Yes, the first parameter to the Add() method is the string key, and the second is your Contact object. You store and lookup objects in the dictionary by the key value - in your case, you would use the Name property of the Contact object you are adding to the collection